# Sql conditional insert or update in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am creating a fee management system using vb.net as my undergraduate project.
I would like to create a form for paying fees and it should be such that once the submit button is clicked,it checks on the database if the admission number already exists(student has paid fees before) then it updates the row by increasing the fee paid by to the new value (amount paid + amount currently in the database) otherwise it creates a new row for the admission number(inserts the details to the database).
I already have the forms but I don't know how to go about the sql part, would someone please help me achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Answer to your question is way too broad and can be achieved in a number of entirely different ways. You need to first learn basic database handling in .NET. Come back with a specific question once you know that part.

Comment: If you want to start somewhere, try learning about one of the two things: DataSets and Entity Framework. Once you know the basics, you'll find that achieving what you have described in far easier than you thought!

Comment: Thanks @dotNET. Would you please provide me with a link to where I can  learn that at a faster pace

Comment: I have a personal inclination towards [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx), but many starters find MSDN a bit too technical. If u feel like that, you may find easy tutorials [elsewhere] (www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p1.html).

Comment: @dotNET I got a way round it from the homeandlearn site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create procedure payAdmission
@admissionnumber int, 
@amountpaid money
as
if exists( select * from admissions where admissionnumber = @admissionnumber)
begin 
    update admissions set amount = amount + @amountpaid 
           where admissionnumber = @admissionnumber 
end 
else 
begin 
    insert into admissions( admissionnumber, amount ) 
         values (@admissionnumber, @amountpaid )
end
```